# Equivalent of NavigationWindow in titanium for android

Tags: android, iphone, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I created an app on iphone now the client wants same on the android platform. The navigation was handled by the navigation window in IOS but can't find anything similar for android. I have tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475240/equivalent-of-ios-createnavigationwindow-in-android) I am using Titanium Alloy framework for developing the app.
Here's the sample code which works for iphone.

```
AlloyView1.xml

<Alloy>
  <NavigationWindow id="navParent">
    <Window>
       <TextField id= "txtUsername" width="120" height = "40"/>
       <Button id="btnNext" width="100" height="40" onClick="goNext"/>
    </Window>
  </NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>



AlloyView1.js

  $.AlloyView1.open();
  var navParentWin = $.navParent;
  function goNext(e){
     var nav
     var controllerView = Alloy.createController('Home').getView();
     navParentWin.openWindow(controllerView);
  }



 Home.xml

  <Alloy>
     <Window>
       <!--  Some View -->
     </Window>
  </Alloy>

home.js
```

// Some code..

```
 function xyz(){
  //something here
  }
```

Comment: maybe go with native features of android , **[Action Bar](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar)**